# Setup PYTHONPATH in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to setup my `PYTHONPATH` in TeamCity. When building, I have the following path that's being created:

```
~/teamcity/buildAgent/work/a_long_id/my_lib
```

My `PYTHONPATH` must point to something that's present in `my_lib`. The problem is that this `a_long_id` can/will/may change, so I would like to use predefined build parameters.

Here is what I came up with at the moment :

```
env.PYTHONPATH        %teamcity.agent.work.dir%/%????%/what/I/wanna/import
```

As you may have guessed, I'm looking for what would replace the `%????%`.

Answer (score 1):

%teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir% is what you're looking for. This is the name of the GUID-like working directory for a given build.

%teamcity.build.checkoutDir% is the full path, including this GUID directory. It would be the equivalent of %teamcity.work.agent.dir%/%teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir%.

An easy way to sort out the multitude of built-in variables for TeamCity is to go to a completed build and check the Parameters tab.